# How do I ease in a drop down with css?

Tags: css

I have a dropdown list that appears when hovering over a list item in a nav. I cant get the drop down to ease in.

Can anyone help me get this ease in transition?

```css
/*style for the list items in the drop down*/

.navDropList .navDropItem {
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
}


/*styling the div that the list resides in*/

.navDropList .dropTag {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #d3d3d3;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}


/*styling drop down list and attempting to set paramaters for transition*/

.navDropList {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #414141;
  padding-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
  padding-left: 0px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5%;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  transition: all .3s ease-in;
  height: 0;
}


/*attempting to make transition. Only displays as block, no ease in*/

.navListItem:hover .navDropList {
  display: block;
  height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="navList">
    <li class=navListItem><a class="navTag current" href="nehemiahUniversity.html">Home</a></li>
    <li class=navListItem><a class="navTag" href="courses.HTML">Courses</a></li>
    <li class=navListItem><a class="navTag" href="training.html">Training Material</a>

      <ul class="navDropList">
        <li class="navDropItem"><a class="dropTag" href="training.html#productionSection">Production</a></li>
        <li class="navDropItem"><a class="dropTag" href="training.html#warehouseSection">Warehouse</a></li>
        <li class="navDropItem"><a class="dropTag" href="training.html#qualitySection">Quality Control</a></li>
        <li class="navDropItem"><a class="dropTag" href="training.html#blendingSection">Blending</a></li>
        <li class="navDropItem"><a class="dropTag" href="training.html#officeSection">Office</a></li>
      </ul>

    </li>
    <li class=navListItem><a class="navTag" href="walkthrough.HTML">Walkthrough</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: @gunther if i set height of the ul to 0, the list items still show. and if i set its opacity to zero as well, the list items go away and the transition animation works, but now there is a bug where my dropdown displays when i hover over the area where it is transparent, not just when i hover over the nav item.

Comment: [`display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/display) property is not animatable, if you want the menu to fade-in you should use the `opacity` property or the `height` property if you want it to slide down. Deleted my comment by mistake before, adding it again for context.

Answer (score 0):

Like Gunther just said when he sniped me. :) If you have `display: none`, the element won't animate.

Apart from opacity, I also added `overflow-y: hidden` and `pointer-events: none`. The first one, so the menu item's doesn't appear outside `.navDropList`, and the second one so that the user can't interact with the items inside `.navDropList` unless it's visible.

Also, never animate using `all`, because that loops through all animatable properties, which can make the animation appear janky, depending on what's happening on your page.

```css
/*style for the list items in the drop down*/

.navDropList .navDropItem {
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
}


/*styling the div that the list resides in*/

.navDropList .dropTag {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #d3d3d3;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}


/*styling drop down list and attempting to set paramaters for transition*/

.navDropList {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #414141;
  padding-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
  padding-left: 0px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5%;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  height: 0;
  
  transition: height 300ms ease-in, opacity 50ms ease-in;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  pointer-events: none;
}


/*attempting to make transition. Only displays as block, no ease in*/

.navListItem:hover .navDropList {
  height: 250px;
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="navList">
    <li class=navListItem><a class="navTag current" href="nehemiahUniversity.html">Home</a></li>
    <li class=navListItem><a class="navTag" href="courses.HTML">Courses</a></li>
    <li class=navListItem><a class="navTag" href="training.html">Training Material</a>

      <ul class="navDropList">
        <li class="navDropItem"><a class="dropTag" href="training.html#productionSection">Production</a></li>
        <li class="navDropItem"><a class="dropTag" href="training.html#warehouseSection">Warehouse</a></li>
        <li class="navDropItem"><a class="dropTag" href="training.html#qualitySection">Quality Control</a></li>
        <li class="navDropItem"><a class="dropTag" href="training.html#blendingSection">Blending</a></li>
        <li class="navDropItem"><a class="dropTag" href="training.html#officeSection">Office</a></li>
      </ul>

    </li>
    <li class=navListItem><a class="navTag" href="walkthrough.HTML">Walkthrough</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: thank you sir you are a gentleman and a scholar. I changed the ms of the opacity ease-in to 300ms, the same as the height. the transition was smoother. thanks man!

Comment: That's a very complete answer! Do you know any other ways aside from `pointer-events: none` to fix the hover problem? I'm thinking that since it creates a new stacking context you might be able to do that with negatives `z-index` but i'm not sure about it

Comment: @Gunther An old trick would be to send it outside of the page with `position: absolute` and `overflow-x: hidden` on the body element. I would honestly go with javascript and generate the content inside a div, like Netflix does when you hover a movie. The "zoomed in" detail view is always the same div, just with different content.